# ASP.Net WebForms IE7 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager

So I've got the following problem. I've created a baseclass for a servercontrol in order to make developing scriptable controls easier.

I went the following way to achieve this:

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(Page.GetType(), "scriptControl.js"))
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page, Page.GetType(), "scriptControl.js", this.ResolveUrl("~/Layouts/scriptControl.js"));

var relScriptPath = GetRelativeScriptUrlPath();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(relScriptPath))
{
    var relativeToken = "relativeScript" + ClientConstructorName;
    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(Page.GetType(), relativeToken))
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page, Page.GetType(), relativeToken, this.ResolveUrl(relScriptPath));
}

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), ClientID, string.Format("scriptControl.registerAndExecute('{0}','{1}');", ClientConstructorName, ClientID), true);
```

Oddly enough this works just fine in pretty much every browser except the <strike>pile of shit</strike> IE7

for most browsers result is:

```
-> load scriptcontrol.js (debug alert notification)
-> load specific.js (debug alert notification)
-> scriptExecute
```

for IE7 the result is:

```
-> load scriptcontrol.js (debug alert notification)
-> scriptExecute (exception. js function as declared in spefific.js not defined because it apparently wasn't run)
```

Did anyone else experience similar issues with it? My research so far did not result in something helpful.

On a sidenote:

my js files are finished with the line which resolved an issue i recall beeing similar before:

```
if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I found the problem. The reason was a comma in an object declaration like

```
{ 
   option, 
   option2,
}
```

Oddly enough this seemed to be enough to bother IE7 so much despite of that declaration postceeding the debugging alert, combined with a entirely useless error message not pointing out the source of error.

Oh well.